# Deploying node app with self-maintained NPM modules

Tags: node.js, git, npm, node-modules

I am developing a very complex app that is using internally developed, open source NPM modules.
I often need to change one of those modules (extra features, bug fixing, etc.) in order for the main application to work.
At the moment, I have:

- A directory called `my_modules`, each containing a git repository one for each module. For example `module1`, `module2`.
- A directory called `my_apps`, where for example there is `app1` which has  `module1` as a dependency
- Under `my_apps/app1/node_modules` I have `module1` and `module2`, installed via NPM
- In the server, deploy by pulling the git repository, running an `npm install` and `npm dedupe`, and running the server with forever.

At this stage, if I have to fix something in one of the modules, I:

- Fix it within `my_apps/app1/node_modules/module1` (not git)
- When it's all working, COPY the files over to `my_modules/module1` and do a `git push` and `npm publish`
- The server will pull the latest modules after deploy thanks to `npm install`

This is way, way less than ideal. It's just too error-prone. However:

- Having a symbolic link link `my_apps/app1/node_modules/module1` => `my_modules/module1` means that module1 will look for dependencies in its own path, which often causes problems (for example, I need to make sure that EVERY module uses the same copy of `module1`, which is imperative)
- Having a git repo under `my_apps/app1/node_modules/module1` feels dangerous, in case I accidentally overwrite changes using NPM on the module. Also, once fixed the change in the local git repo, I would still then need to pull the changes in `my_modules/module1`. Yes a step forward from copying files over...

What's the "recommended" way of dealing with this? Any best practices?

Comment: If you vote for closing, please explain why. I think it's a legitimate question for a developer.